# Salto de linea en javascript / ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de escribir/editar tengo la etiqueta (contenteditable)

Al momento de editar no guarda el salto de linea PERO, coloco el salto en linea en codigo html o le agrego el tag \r, actualiza el codigo y me da el salto de linea.

bueno le agrego imagen para explicarme mejor.

Como deseo que guarde:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como guarda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le agrego el salto en linea \r \n y 
:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y resulta que si me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasemos al codigo.

Tengo la informacion:

```
<td id="Cel:<?php echo $id; ?>" contenteditable="true"> <div style="width: 700px"><?php echo str_replace("\r", "<br>",$cel); ?><div></td>
```

Lo cual esta dentro de un **while**

Envio la informacion mediante un boton:

```
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick="realizaProceso(<?php echo $id ;?>); return false;" value="Enviar" /></td>
```

Lo recibe:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        //Mensaje
        var message_status = $("#status");
        $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var value = $(this).text();
            $.post('editar.php' , id + "=" + value, function(data){
                if(data != '')
              {
                message_status.show();
                message_status.html(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.html("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE");},2000);
              } else {
                //message_status().html = data;
              }
          });
        });
      });
```

El PHP que edita la base de datos:

```
foreach($_POST as $rownumber_name => $val) {

//remember to clean post values
 $rownumber = $rownumber_name;
 $val = $val;
 //from the fieldname:rownumber_id we need to get rownumber_id
  $split_data = explode(':', $rownumber);
  $rownumber_id = $split_data[1];
  $rownumber_name = $split_data[0];
$sql_1 = "UPDATE `menssagee` SET `text_message` = '$val' WHERE `id` = $rownumber_id";
if ($db->query($sql_1)) {
$last_id = $db->insert_id;
//echo $sql_1;
echo "Registro Editado Correctamente: <img src='images/loader.gif' height='15px'>";
} else {
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);
}
}
```

He intentado antes de guarda los datos colocarle la funcion de str_replace a la variable (val), pero aun asi no me guarda el salto de linea.

---

Actualizacion:

Codigo JS

```js
$("#texto").on('blur', actualiza);
var message_status = $("#status");
function actualiza() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    let valor = $("#texto").text();
    console.log(valor);
    $('#formato').html(valor);
    $('#sinbr').html(valor);
    $('#conbr').html(valor.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));

    $.post('editar.php', id + "=" + valor, function (data) {
      if (data != '') {
        message_status.show();
        message_status.html(data);
        setTimeout(function() {
          message_status.html("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO");
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        message_status().html = data;
      }
    });
}

actualiza();
```

El envio de datas me esta dando lio en este momento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con `<?php echo nl2br($cel); ?>`

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero pruebes usar algún elemento de Texto Enriquecido; desde luego esto implicara que tu campo en la BD para ese dato deberá ser más grande por los tags html que se agregan. Así te evitas esos dolores de cabeza y con CSS controlas apariencia.

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. @triby intente pero aun asi no funciona deja el texto tal como esta no modifica nada

Comment: @RobertoLeOr el campo de la base de datos esta en text https://prnt.sc/tmsq5n

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer, el problema es que `jQuery.text()` devuelve solo el texto del contenedor, eliminando etiquetas y saltos de línea. Usando funciones nativas de javascript e `innerText` se respetan los saltos de línea.

Para agregar la información en la petición AJAX, es conveniente usar [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) en lugar de ponerlos en una cadena y enviar por pares `nombre -> valor` para facilitar su manejo al procesar en PHP.

```js
// Contenedor para mensajes de resultados
let message_status = $('#message-status');

// Asignar evento a celdas con contenido editable
$("td[contenteditable=true]").on('blur', actualiza);

// Recibir evento como parámetro
function actualiza(e) {
    // Obtener elemento editado desde el evento, con target
    let item = e.target;
    // Separar letras y números de ID
    let [prefijo, id] = item.id.split('-');
    let text_message = item.innerText;
    
    // Verificando que se puede obtener ID
    console.log(prefijo, id);
    
    // Preparar datos para enviar por formulario
    let datos = {
        "id": id,
        "text_message": text_message
    };

    $.post('editar.php',
        datos,
        function(data) {
            if(data != '') {
                message_status.show();
                message_status.html(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function() {
                    message_status.html("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE");
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                message_status().html = data;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

```css
#texto, #formato, #sinbr, #conbr, #conbr2 {
    margin:20px;
    padding:10px;
}

#texto { background:#eee; }
#formato { background:#fee; white-space:pre-wrap; }
#sinbr { background:#efe; }
#conbr { background:#eef; }
#conbr2 { background:#ffd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="message-status"></div>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="Cel-123" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>
<br>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Después, en PHP puedes acceder a cada elemento por su nombre (id y text_message) y debes escapar el valor del texto para evitar errores en la consulta.

```
<?php
// Asegurar que ID está presente en $_POST y es numérico
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? (int) $_POST['id'] : 0;
$text_message = (isset($_POST['text_message'])) ? $_POST['text_message'] : 0;

// Validar la información
if($id <= 0) {
    die('ID incorrecta, debe ser mayor que cero.');
}
if(trim($text_message) == '') {
    die('El texto no puede quedar vacío.');
}
// Preparar texto para insertar en base de datos,
// la función correcta depende del motor y librería que estás usando
// este ejemplo funciona con mysqli
$text_message = $db->real_escape_string($text_message);

$sql_1 = "UPDATE `menssagee` SET `text_message` = '$text_message' WHERE `id` = $id";
if ($db->query($sql_1)) {
    echo "Registro Editado Correctamente: <img src='images/loader.gif' height='15px'>";
} else {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);
}
```

**Muy importante:** Te estoy sugiriendo [preparar los datos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) con una función de la librería *mysqli* porque desconozco lo que estás usando. Debes adaptarlo de acuerdo a lo que tienes en tu clase de conexión a base de datos.

Si bien, esto puede solucionar el problema al actualizar, lo ideal es que uses consultas preparadas para mejorar la seguridad en tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. En esta ocasion no me funciona ninguna de las dos puede que sea el tema de HTML en el primer ensayo no sucede nada y lo hago en otro archivo y no me funciona. Con respecto al segundo ensayo me sale un mensaje de error en la linea 4 "document.querySelector" https://prnt.sc/tr9ozx como puede ver. Hice una adaptacion de tu codigo con el mio y aun asi no funciona.

Comment: Ese error es porque no existe el contenedor. Edita la pregunta para poner tu código actual y tratar de ver porqué es el error.

Comment: Por eso te digo que es extraño porque lo que hago es copiar todo tu codigo tanto el JS y el HTML creo un archivo nuevo y sale el codigo. Ya actualizo el codigo.

Comment: listo alli esta la actualizacion espero que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Copiaste el ejemplo completo, donde solo mencionaba cómo resolver el problema de saltos de línea y necesitaba adaptaciones. Actualicé la respuesta, ya debe funcionar.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Triby por la ayuda, al hacer click fuera del div sale un mensaje de error: https://prnt.sc/trto2j, no permite actualizar el texto incluso tu ejemplo sale el mismo mensaje de error. (Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.)

Prove colocando

Comment: A _jQuery.post_ parece no gustarle el FormData y hay que enviar objeto o cadena. revisa la actualización.

Comment: Excelente amigo, le tuve que hacerle algunas modificaciones a tu codigo para que me funcione. lo mas relevante de la modificacion fue: str_replace no es \r sino \n, en JS: el ID no lo traia, modifique por  `código`let id = $(this).attr("id");`código`, de otra forma no me daba el id y tienes que declarar message_status.

Comment: En cuanto al ID, se obtiene sin problemas, funciona bien en el fragmento de código y en PHP solo recibes el número sin `Cel-` (usa guion para separar, no dos puntos). Y se supone que no hagas modificaciones al contenido para guardar en base de datos, solo para mostrarlos y, de cualquier forma, se debería hacer en PHP.